# How to insert mysql fetched data again into database tableE

Tags: php, database

How to insert mysql fetched data again into database table And I don’t know how do it cause td tag can’t have a name. Somebody help

Comment: What do you mean under `td tag can’t have a name`?

Comment: If you want to send data back from the client to the server, then you need _form fields_ to do that, not (just) table cells. (Or you need to read the content from the table cells, and send it back using AJAX. But if you _had_ no form fields for the user to edit the data in some way, then why would you want to send it back to the server, by a round-trip via the client, in the first place? Sending information to the server it already knows, would make rather little sense.)